# Invalid NULL assignment R when having to assign a variable to a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, igraph

I see many people running into a similar issue with great answers but I believe this is an unanswered variation to this question!

I have a graph

```
g <- reactive(graph_from_dataframe(df))
```

Now I want to assign a `degree` property to this.

```
V(g())$degree <- degree(g())
```

This howevers throws the null assignment error but I don't know how to assign it without calling g. I avoided this by assigning the degree property inside an output$... however this heavily violates DRY and leads to double degree calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that `reactive(.)` objects take assignments.

Two thoughts:

1. Use `reactiveVal`:

   ```r
   g <- reactiveVal()
   observeEvent(df, {
     newg <- graph_from_dataframe(df)
     V(newg)$degree <- degree(new)
     g(newg)
   })
   ```
2. Handle the `$degree` assignment in the original `reactive`:

   ```r
   g <- reactive({
     newg <- graph_from_dataframe(df)
     V(newg)$degree <- degree(newg)
     newg
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following syntax should work

```
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)
```